# What does c mean in Calculus (Absolute Value Inequality)?

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value

I am graphing Absolute Value Inequalities and I came across this problem. |x-*c*| < 0.1. I'm not sure what *c* represents in this inequality.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Absent context, we can only guess.  My guess would be that $c$ is a fixed real number and that you are asked to describe the set of real numbers $x$ for which that inequality holds.

Comment: If $|x-c|<0.1,$ then $x-c<0.1$ and $c-x<0.1,$ so $c-0.1<x<c+0.1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner How then, would I graph that?

Comment: you could show an open interval $ (c-0.1, c+0.1) $ on a number line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that $c$ is a fixed real number in this problem, not a special calculus symbol.

$|x-c|<0.1$ means $x-c<0.1$ and $c-x<0.1$, so $c-0.1<x<c+0.1$,

i.e., $x\in(c-0.1,c+0.1)$.

This could be shown on a number line as follows (pardon my lack of artistic skill):

<----------------|----------------------|---------------(=$\equiv$=)----|------------->

where "(" represents $c-0.1$, "$\equiv$" represents $c$, and ")" represents $c+0.1$.

Comment: you will see this a lot in calculus:  for example, defining limits or continuity, $|x-c|<\delta$

Comment: $x$ is in a neighborhood of $c$